# Printing values in an object to columns in google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an object filled via this piece of code:

```
for ( i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
  var num = array[i];
  result[num] = result[num] ? result[num]+1 : 1;
} 
Logger.log(result);
```

Now I want to print set te values of a column in my spreadsheet to the counted values. The data in the object looks like this:

```
{git-b-60=2.0, sax-c-12=6.0, ......}
```

And it continues on like this, and will get bigger in the future.

Now I also have a column with these course codes (the git-b-60 is a course code) in chronological order, and would love for the number values in the object to be printed in the column after the corresponding course code.

Is there a way to do it? Because I'm stumped. I can't seem to find the way to print values from an object to the columns.

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to construct a 2 dimensional array and then use `setValues(2D Array)`

```
var outerArray = [],
    thisValue = "",
    innerArray = [];

for (var key in result) {
  innerArray = []; //Reset on every loop
  thisValue = result[key];
  innerArray.push(thisValue);
  outerArray.push(innerArray);
};

var numberOfRowsToWrite = outerArray.length;

SpreadsheetApp
  .getActiveSpreadsheet()
  .getSheetByName(name)
  .getRange(row to start at, column to start at, numberOfRowsToWrite, 1)
  .setValues(outerArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help with this one! This worked wonders for printing the values from the object, even though it still seems to shuffle the values around. Do you know of any way to make these values match the corresponding course codes? e.g. I have column R with the course codes, and want to print te corresponding attendance numbers in column S.

Comment: JavaScript will change the order in which elements are stored in an object from the order in which the code runs.  Arrays won't ever change the order.  Does either the key or the value have some kind of information that indicates what column it should go into?  If so, you could create an object that matches the value to the column.  Then you'd need to either have multiple `for` loops, one for each column, or have a nested `for` loop.  The outer loop would need to loop once for every column, the inner loop would need to go through the entire set of data for every column.

Comment: Uff I'm still not versed enough in JavaScript I see. So I have this column with course codes in the destination sheet, sorted chronologically. The numbers we have in object are the number of attendees for particular courses. You seem to say that I'd have to get the values from that chronologically sorted column into an array, and then work with that? Here is a link to the test sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ozfNvfFjoe5ISAKz58QdTNNBI2AakaWNxwDHdI6VZws/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I took a look at the spreadsheet.  Chronological means it's sorted by date/time.  I'm trying to figure out what all the connections might be.  I just re-read your question.   If you found the matching course code in the destination sheet, and wrote the correct number value into the "Cursusvulling" column, would that be what you need?  If so, you could  build the array by testing every single value, finding the match, and putting data into the array in the correct order before setting the values.    Is the object coming from a source outside of the spreadsheet?  So, you have no control over it?

Comment: Okay so I meant chronological in the way that the oldest course was at the top, etc. Since, in the working environment, this is actually across different spreadsheets, I couldn't use the usual countif formula. In essence, I can't change the order of the 'datasheet' part, since that would muck up some other stuff my boss made, and be less clear in general. So yeah the object is coming from another spreadsheet, and I do have some -restricted- control over it. And you're right; if the number was written to "Cursusvulling" next to the matching course code, that would be the resultt I'm looking for